# ul li timetable elements overlapping

Tags: html, css

Making a responsive timetable which switches to a list format for mobile, with Weekdays acting as headers and relevant sessions being listed below.
I've encountered a problem where li elements overlap. Despite experimenting with position and display values, I can't figure out how to counteract this overlap.
Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.smallTableContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.weekdayHeader {
  background: #bc4b51;
  color: #efefef;
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.sessions {
  padding: 0;
}

.className {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-size: 13pt;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.classTime {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="smallTableContainer">
  <h3 class="weekdayHeader">Monday</h3>
  <ul class="sessions">
    <li>
      <div class="className">
        Warrior Cubs Kickboxing
        <br>AGES 5-7
        <br>[ SPACES AVAILABLE ] </div>
      <div class="classTime">
        <br> 16.15pm - 17.00pm
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="className">
        Warrior Cubs Kickboxing
        <br>AGES 8-12
        <br>[ SPACES AVAILABLE ]
      </div>
      <div class="classTime">
        <br> 17.00pm - 17.45pm
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your desired result correctly, you want the events and times to disaply on individual lines. In order to do this, all you're looking for is `cleart: both` on your `.sessions li`. In addition to this, you'll probably want to add a bit of spacing between each event, which can be done by adding `margin-top` to the (rather complex) `.sessions li:not(:first-of-type) .className` selector. This ensures that the margin will be applied to all of the listings apart from the first one.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.smallTableContainer {
  position: relative;
  /*display: none;*/
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.weekdayHeader {
  background: #bc4b51;
  color: #efefef;
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.sessions {
  padding: 0;
}

.sessions li {
  clear: both;
}

.className {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-size: 13pt;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.classTime {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.sessions li:not(:first-of-type) .className {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="smallTableContainer">
  <h3 class="weekdayHeader">Monday</h3>
  <ul class="sessions">
    <li>
      <div class="className">
        Warrior Cubs Kickboxing
        <br>AGES 5-7
        <br>[ SPACES AVAILABLE ] </div>
      <div class="classTime">
        <br> 16.15pm - 17.00pm
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="className">
        Warrior Cubs Kickboxing
        <br>AGES 8-12
        <br>[ SPACES AVAILABLE ]
      </div>
      <div class="classTime">
        <br> 17.00pm - 17.45pm
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: works great! thanks my friend. one more question. if you have a look on my test server http://mintrain.co.uk/timetable , the divs classTime and className appear to display outside of the <li> elements. any ideas? *EDIT: note this is when the screen is less than 900px width

Comment: @JackScott - You could add `overflow: hidden` to the `<li>` elements to have them correctly contained in that regard... though this isn't really required (and will have no real 
 visible 'effect', as the `<li>` elements do not have a height); it just would help improve layout when viewing the page with the Developer Tools :)

Comment: hm, but according to developer tools the <li> elements are taking up vertical space and creating undesired gaps

Comment: i've figured it out. there's a style applied to 'ul li' much earlier in styles.css - this is styling the menu in the top left corner. how do i fix this so i can have seperate styles for separate ul li's